# problem with multi thread and socket programming(multi connection)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a server/client program 
the first thread is for shell commands through TCP
the second thread capture screen shot and send that through TCP
the last thread sends an array through Tcp

now I want to create one connection for each thread 
how I should implement that ?(I have just one port , no more...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just like to kindly point out that your question is a little too general for Stack Overflow but I will do my best to try and answer you.

So the short answer is that this cannot be done. You cannot have multiple sockets bound on the same port for one given host. Concretely, this means that you won't be able to bind multiple sockets to, say, `127.0.0.1:7777`, only one socket can be bound per port.

If I were you though, I would consider only having one single TCP socket for the entire program. Having a TCP connection for each thread seems useless to me but again, you didn't provide a lot of information on the context and the limitations that you have.

So you could have:

- Your main thread that reads the standard input for command lines and
  posts messages to be sent on the socket in a 'network thread'
  described below.
- Your 'screenshot thread' would also post messages to be sent in a
  queue that will be read by a 'network thread'
- Same for your 'array thread'
- Finally, you have a network thread that could use what is known as
  **synchronization mechanisms** to read the message queue in a thread safe
  manner and send every message that is posted to the queue by other
  threads.

(again I'm trying to be as clear as possible but I can only do with the information I am provided with)

From here, you could do some more ample research on thread safe ways to queue messages, [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) seems like a good starting point.

Search for python synchronization mechanisms, thread safe queues or lists and sockets, those queries should yield some interesting results!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply....Actually one connection is always busy for sending screenshots from client to server ...now how can I send commands to client ?

Comment: Well, in that case you'd have to open a second socket. Why is it that you can't listen on more than one port?